# moment.js compare dates via .diff()

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Im having problems when I try to compare 2 dates.

```
var end = moment(items[i].dateEnd).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
var now = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Example: `now = '29/10/2015'` and `end = '30/06/2015'`

Tried using `.diff()` function from [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) without any result, like this:

```
end.diff(now);
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: You want to *compare* or to get the difference ? And what kind of comparision?

Comment: I want to know if one date (now) is greater than other (end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with specifying input date format:

```
moment(items[i].dateEnd, 'DD/MM/YYYY').diff(moment());
```

Comment: It suit my needs. Also found a solution, instead normal dates, I was using unix format, is just compare 2 numbers, like this `moment().format('x');` Thanks @hsz